# Are there any keyboard shortcuts for Windows 10 developer preview's virtual desktops ("Task View")?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, windows-10-preview

I just installed Windows 10 developer preview but can't figure out how to cycle through the new virtual desktops with the keyboard.

I'm looking for the following shortcuts if they exist:

- Switch to the next/previous desktop
- Go to desktop number *N*
- Close the current desktop
- Open a new desktop

Are these controls implemented yet?

Comment: related: https://superuser.com/questions/950452/how-to-quickly-move-current-window-to-another-task-view-desktop-in-windows-10

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**- Switch to the next/previous desktop:**

<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

> The Windows-Tab shortcut lets you switch between multiple virtual desktops with different arrangements of applications

[Source](http://www.techradar.com/reviews/pc-mac/software/operating-systems/windows-10-1267364/review)

> You can switch between your open virtual desktops using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> or <kbd>Right</kbd> arrow keys.

[Source](https://superuser.com/a/819770/23133)

**- Go to desktop number N:**

Currently unknown, or not implemented.

**- Close the current desktop:**

<kbd>WIN</kbd> + <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd>

[Source](http://blogs.windows.com/bloggingwindows/2014/10/03/keyboard-shortcuts-in-the-windows-10-technical-preview/)

**- Open a new desktop:**

<kbd>WIN</kbd> + <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>

[Source](http://blogs.windows.com/bloggingwindows/2014/10/03/keyboard-shortcuts-in-the-windows-10-technical-preview/)

Comment: Thanks, after trying for 5 minutes, i finally figured out that after having brought this UI with Windows+Tab to the screen, you still have to press Tab once more before being able to use the arrows keys to select the desired desktop. It is pretty confusing.

Comment: If I figure out any of the others you're requesting I'll post them, but so far I think they just don't exist.

Comment: Microsoft just made a blog post about it : http://blogs.windows.com/bloggingwindows/2014/10/03/keyboard-shortcuts-in-the-windows-10-technical-preview/?utm_source=twitterfeed&utm_medium=twitter
I edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: So no shortcuts to move windows from one to another virtual desktop (yet)?

Comment: The latest technical preview update just introduced this feature : Windows Key + Shift + Arrow Key (I haven't tried it yet though)
(http://www.cnet.com/news/updated-windows-10-technical-preview-build-9860/)

Comment: Is there a shortcut for sending a Window to a desktop? 
Like Shift+Win+Left (might work to use Ctl+Shift+Win+Left). (this doesn't work for WTP9860)

Comment: as soon as anyone hears about any utility that enhances virtual desktops in windows 10, let me know.. things like more shortcut keys to switch to a specific desktop # like win-ctrl-number or something like that would be nice.I know you can use xmbc to assign next/previous desktops to the mouse - so you could _for instance switch desktops scrolling the mouse wheel over the taskbar if you set it up that way_. But I would like some hot keys to move to a specific desktop. Also a (switch back to last desktop key would be awesome)

Comment: @Mikey You (and everyone :) ) should go here and add your request(s) to the list (or add you comments if it exists already): https://windows.uservoice.com/forums/265757-windows-feature-suggestions?query=virtual%20desktop%20shortcuts

Comment: wow cool, I never thought MS would have such a site.. wonder how many versions of windows it has been around for - holy #$@$ they actually implemented the ability to drag windows to another virtual desktop

Answer (score 14):

You can switch between your open virtual desktops using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> or <kbd>Right</kbd> arrow keys.

Answer (score 4):

**Snapping window:** WIN + LEFT or RIGHT (can be used with UP or DOWN to get into quadrants)

**Switch to recent window:** ALT + TAB (unchanged) – Hold shows new Task view window view, let go and switches to app.

**Task view:** WIN + TAB – New Task view opens up and stays open.

**Create new virtual desktop:** WIN + CTRL + D

**Close current virtual desktop:** WIN + CTRL + F4

**Switch virtual desktop:** WIN + CTRL + LEFT or RIGHT

source : [microsoft blog post](http://blogs.windows.com/bloggingwindows/2014/10/03/keyboard-shortcuts-in-the-windows-10-technical-preview/?utm_source=twitterfeed&utm_medium=twitter)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the keyboard combination: "CTRL + WIN + ARROW-KEY LEFT/RIGHT" in order to switch between your virtual desktops.

Edit:
Just saw that someone else answered with the above. My bad for "double post".