# How to quickly move current window to another Task View / desktop in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10

Windows 10 introduced *Task View* - the ability to have multiple virtual desktops. When I am in a window on Desktop 1, what's the quickest way to move it to Desktop 2?

Currently, I need to enter the task switcher (icon in the Taskbar or <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>), find the window, and drag & drop it between desktops. It is inconvenient. Is there a quicker way?

Comment: This is how I do it and the only way I know how to do it. Press the **Windows key + Tab** . Press **Tab again** . This removes the outline from the active program thumbnail and Task View interface active. Use the arrow keys to move among the desktops on the Task View interface. When you have highlighted the desktop to which you want to switch, press **Enter** .

Comment: Oooooo you can try **WINKEY + CTRL + LEFT ARROW** or **WINKEY + CTRL + RIGHT ARROW**

Comment: This is not about navigating between desktops, it is about moving windows from one desktop to another. And yes, Ctrl+Win+left/right is cool :)

Comment: When to expect a Windows build in hotkey for it?

Comment: @Borek Does any of the answers satisfy you?

Comment: can we expect to receive a built-in Windows keyboard shortcut before the AI overlords take over?

Comment: If you want a native shortcut, I suggest upvoting [this suggestion in the MS Feedback Hub](https://aka.ms/AA2dqfg).

Comment: I wish there was just a numbered option, e.g. **Winkey** + **ctrl** + **2** to send to desktop 2. And **Winkey** + **ctrl** + **+/-** to send to next/previous desktop. I used to have an Nvidia driver or something that could do this and made it so easy.

Answer (score 188):

I think for a quicker switch this should be in the titlebar, so I created a tool for that:

https://github.com/Eun/MoveToDesktop

[image]

You can also move windows by using <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd> or change the shortcut as needed.

Comment: (y) Excellant work. Thanks. BTW, why does it need both x86 and x64 version of Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015 even when my processor and OS both are x64?

Comment: Yes! Finally!!! Thank you so much! :) As an Ubuntu user I was super excited about Virtual Desktops in Windows 10... but without this hotkey feature it felt useless. Now the feature is finally complete :) Thanks for your efforts and thanks for open sourcing it.

Comment: OK, call me an idiot, but "Download and Run" is a bit cynical... I have downloaded the zip. Run... what? I have tried opening the solution in VisualStudio 2015 Community, but nothing happens. What am I missing? Do I need to build it? Build what then? Looks amazing, please help me use it.

Comment: Download `MoveToDesktop-X.Y.zip` from the Releases section. In there is an `.exe` file, extract it somewhere and run it. No need for Visual Studio 2015. You might just need to install the Visual C++ Redistributable package.

Comment: Releases section... That was the key. Makes sense, too. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Eun: cool. thx! Might want to mention the thing about the release secton in the readme. Downloading the source had me thinking "oh, this is too techy for me". I was expecting the zip to also contain the source. Or is this a common GitHub thing all other users expect this way?

Comment: @Wouter You would normaly check the release section :). But there is a big Download button on the page ;)

Comment: This tool did not work.

Comment: wonder when windows will add drag and drop to the virtual desktops screen - that would be _amazing_

Comment: @Mikey They added that a long time ago. I have had it since I first started using Win 10.

Comment: @Ninjakannon sorry, I should have been more specific. I mean to drag one window from any desktop to another - without having to switch to that desktop first, i.e. from the thumbnail windows. And also the ability to drag the virtual desktops around, to rearrange the order.

Comment: @Mikey If you press Win + tab, you can drag windows from the current desktop to any other. I'm not sure it makes sense to want to drag a window from a desktop you are not on, that could get very confusing!

Comment: @Eun The tool seems great! Which version of the Visual C++ Redistributable Package is necessary? When I simply run the downloaded .exe file it doesn't add the Window option nor the shortcuts.

Comment: @Eun never mind. After a Windows Update it's working without installing any further packages. Works like a charm!

Comment: Awesome! - @borek I think this can be marked as answer.

Comment: @vacip I did that too. Instead of downloading from the clone or download box on the upper right as you normally would, scroll down to the green download button probably about half way down the page. Download from there and it will be an exe file instead of a zip.

Comment: @Ninjakannon No, I believe Mikey is talking about being able to drag the window over the sides of the screen into the next desktop without changing view. Just like it is in almost all linux desktops and on Ubuntu Unity. There is also usually a setting for the snappiness which allows the user to still snap to the side but if using more force or momentum then then the user would be able to drag the window past the border into the next virtual desktop instead of snapping.

Comment: Works for me. Thanks.  The default hotkeys couldn't be registered, but after changing them it works great!

Comment: As a Linux user forced to use Windows at work, this is exactly what I was looking for. I use virtual desktops a lot and features like this to speed up workflow mean a lot. Thanks! It's a shame Microsoft seems to be ignoring so many useful features common in Linux distros.

Comment: Quite a lot of malware detections  https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/dcaa40b0dbffbaaa25f9b97d72a8a50beb94763c58213c45afeb142f63666003/detection. Hopefully, all benign.

Comment: @ArtemRussakovskii really? did anyone else confirm this? really needed a tool like this.. it's sad if it comes with malware

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot Eun.

Comment: Does this no longer work with the latest update to Windows?

Comment: This appears to be exactly what I've been looking for. Unfortunately, with so may red flags on VirusTotal, I just can't bring myself to use it. I post this in case others care similarly about such things: https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/dcaa40b0dbffbaaa25f9b97d72a8a50beb94763c58213c45afeb142f63666003/detection

Comment: Awesome! Works very well. Just like Linux now.

Comment: It is an archived (unmaintained) repo, and unfortunately it does not work in windows 11, it only works in windows 10

Answer (score 108):

I also looked for that option, and from the searches I've made (I think that I also saw it on the Microsoft forums), it's not something that is available built-in at the moment.

The best way I came out with for now, to avoid using the mouse, is:

- <kbd>Winkey</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd> for the desktops screen
- Right click on the window you want to move.
  Use the right click keyboard button, or <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd> if you don't have that key in your keyboard.
- Choose `Move to` (or type `M`, because it's marked), and then the desktop you want (or `N` for new desktop, also marked)

This doesn't help that much, but that's what there is until someone develops something to make it easier.

**Update:** I've started looking into this. There's a registry value that changes when the app is moved between desktops.  In that location, there are all the open apps:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\SessionInfo\1\ApplicationViewManagement 
(I guess the session number will change if there is more than one logged in).
```

The id of the current desktop is here:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\SessionInfo\1\VirtualDesktops\CurrentVirtualDesktop
```

It's not enough to change it to the other virtual desktop key because some UI refresh is needed.

I've checked with procmon, and the dll's that are used in the process are:

- msctf.dll
- twinui.dll
- windows.immersiveshell.serviceprovider.dll
- shell32.dll
- UIAnimation.dll

I'll guess that one of them is responsible for the visual refresh, and the main suspect is UIAnimation.dll!

If someone wants to keep investigating, this will serve as a start.

Comment: After pressing Win + Tab, you can also simply drag the window to the desktop you want.

Comment: @Nearoo which kind of loses the point of doing it fast - mostly without the mouse.

Comment: @arieljannai Nah, dragging it is most probably faster than having to right click, open the submenu and clicking on the desktop. A shortcut like on Linux would be best, though.

Comment: Just learned something new and useful Shift + F10  = right click

Comment: It's worked for me, but it's interesting that windows has not any shortcut for that

Comment: In 20H2, M for Move is not marked, and pressing the M key in the context menu does nothing. Is there a way to enable that?

Comment: @Nearoo that's the way I do it, one simple gesture instead of a series of clicks

Answer (score 28):

## Yet another AHK Script

```
#Left::
  WinGetTitle, Title, A
  WinSet, ExStyle, ^0x80, %Title%
  Send {LWin down}{Ctrl down}{Left}{Ctrl up}{LWin up}
  sleep, 50
  WinSet, ExStyle, ^0x80, %Title%
  WinActivate, %Title%
Return

#Right::
  WinGetTitle, Title, A
  WinSet, ExStyle, ^0x80, %Title%
  Send {LWin down}{Ctrl down}{Right}{Ctrl up}{LWin up}
  sleep, 50
  WinSet, ExStyle, ^0x80, %Title%
  WinActivate, %Title%
Return
```

This moves the active window left or right with the win+arrow keys.
Tested on Win10 Version 10.0.17134.1365 with animations off.

Comment: Works fluently, also with more than two virtual desktops.

Comment: This works well! I copied this to my own script, an added a hotkey to move the current window to a _new_ desktop, by changing the `Send` line to `Send {LWin down}{Ctrl down}d{Ctrl up}{LWin up}`

Comment: Note that `#Left` and `#Right` conflicts with the shortcuts to snap windows to the side of the screen. Modified it to `!#Left` and `!#Right` (Win + Alt + arrow)

Comment: I'm on Win10Pro and when I ran the script, I got an error "Keyboard/Mouse hook could not be activated". I was able to get it working by changing the hotkeys and removing the navigation Left/Right (e.g. using ^#j works). Any ideas why the navigation keys don't work?

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work with my "VcXsrv X Server" windows. And they are actually the ones I care most about :-( The don't seem to be affected by the `WinSet, ExStyle, ^0x80, %Title%` commands.

Comment: Great! I combined this with showing the **name of the current virtual desktop** from https://stackoverflow.com/a/73624889/1265192

Comment: not a quick way

Comment: AHK v2 version if somebody needs it

```ahk
; WIN + ALT + LEFT/RIGHT to move window to left/right monitor
!#Left:: {
    hWnd := WinExist("A") ; Get the unique ID of the active window
    WinSetExStyle("^0x80", "ahk_id " . hWnd)
    Send("{LWin down}{Ctrl down}{Left}{Ctrl up}{LWin up}")
    Sleep(50)
    WinSetExStyle("^0x80", "ahk_id " . hWnd)
    WinActivate("ahk_id " . hWnd)
    Return
}
```

Comment: and right:
```ahk
!#Right:: {
    hWnd := WinExist("A") ; Get the unique ID of the active window
    WinSetExStyle("^0x80", "ahk_id " . hWnd)
    Send("{LWin down}{Ctrl down}{Right}{Ctrl up}{LWin up}")
    Sleep(50)
    WinSetExStyle("^0x80", "ahk_id " . hWnd)
    WinActivate("ahk_id " . hWnd)
    Return
}
```

Comment: @BramSchoenmakers This is an improvement, but note that while `#Left` and `#Right` are reserved for moving windows in 1/2 screen width increments, as of Windows 11 23H2, `!#Left` and `!#Right` are used for the same purpose but for 1/3 screen width increments, introducing another conflict. Use `^#!Left` and `^#!Right` (Ctrl + Win + Alt + Arrow) instead, or alternatively `^+!Left` and `^+!Right` (Ctrl + Shift + Alt + Arrow).

Answer (score 23):

UPDATE: It seam to stop working on latest Windows and this project is discontinued by author...

I use [Windows 10 Virtual Desktop Enhancer](https://github.com/sdias/win-10-virtual-desktop-enhancer).

Just [download](https://github.com/sdias/win-10-virtual-desktop-enhancer/releases/latest) it, run it (and configure [autostart](https://github.com/sdias/win-10-virtual-desktop-enhancer/blob/master/docs/installation.md#autostart) if you need).

Then you can simply press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Arrow Left</kbd> / <kbd>Arrow  Right</kbd> and it will move you app to other desktop and switch to that desktop.

Comment: The script didn't work for me, but the release exe does. Nice solution!

Comment: simple, transparent, easy to install = perfect!

Comment: I can't get Win+Ctrl+Shift+Left/Right to work recently. Does this still work for anyone else?

Comment: @AndrewRalon Yeah, I also checked and it seams to not work on latest Windows :/

Comment: Without trying the AutoHotKey software, this doesn't seem to work on Win 10 Pro (build 19041.630)

Comment: One can fix the official, but discontinued [Windows 10 Virtual Desktop Enhancer](https://github.com/sdias/win-10-virtual-desktop-enhancer) by replacing the `virtual-desktop-accessor.dll` as described in this [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/AutoHotkey/comments/cvjfi4/virtual_desktop_enhancer_ahk_solution_seems_to_be/).

1. Get the latest official version [here](https://github.com/sdias/win-10-virtual-desktop-enhancer/releases/tag/0.11.2).
2. Replace `virtual-desktop-accessor.dll` in `libraries` with the one from [this fork](https://github.com/lschwahn/win-10-virtual-desktop-enhancer).

Comment: **It does not work on Windows 10**

Comment: @ToJo The .dll replacement not only fixes the keyboard shortcuts, but also adds indicator with desktop number, a very useful touch. Thanks!!!

Comment: Worked perfectly for me without any modification, I'm on last version of W10. Thanks @CichyK24!

Comment: it is not a quick way when needing to install some 3rd party stuff when there's a built-in way doing so

Answer (score 20):

At this level of managing Windows, I really think you should use a third-party program to help out. My own solution to this was to add a simple shortcut to [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com/) (AHK):

```
#|::Send, +{F10}M{Enter}
```

`#|` is the shortcut, which translates to <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>|</kbd>

On my keyboard, that makes sense, as <kbd>|</kbd> is above <kbd>Tab</kbd>, but you could change it to whatever suits your need.

Using [above answer by arieljannai](https://superuser.com/a/950507/), by sending <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>, <kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the marked window will be moved to the other virtual desktop if you're juggling between two.

For an introduction to AHK, please see https://autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm.

Comment: *F10* does nothing on my computer. The *contextual menu* key of my (French) keyboard does the job though.

Comment: `win+Tab, context, V, Enter ` on Swiss-german setup

Comment: F10 alone does not bring up context menu, you must hold shift (denoted by + in AHK above). updated answer to reflect the typo.

Comment: I thought a program called Windows would manage windows just fine? ;)

Comment: This solution requires pressing Win+Tab first. Personally, I wanted to avoid that step (and the time it takes, especially when the CPU is busy which causes a delay).

Answer (score 16):

I'm not sure why this hasn't been mentioned above, but the following is the *native* way to do this, without downloading helpers.

1. <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> to quickly see all applications/windows
   (if you have multiple monitors, there will be one list on each monitor for each virtual desktop).
2. Right click on the application/window you want to move over, hover on **Move to**, and select the desktop you want send the application to.

Before I found this, I even tried the *MoveToDesktop* project posted above, but I find this just as easy, and the *MoveToDesktop* menu doesn't seem to appear on all applications anyway (for example, not Chrome nor Sublime at the moment).

Comment: Too bad that there is still not hotkey for it. Though this works nice too.

Comment: Once you have the desktops setup its rare that you need to move things over, no?

Comment: I move screens from monitor 1 to 2 all the time with a hotkey. I move between desktops all the time with a hotkey, so why not a hotkey to move a window between virtual desktops? And I mean a native hotkey build in win10

Comment: It would be nice indeed.

Comment: What has been so nice for *many years* in Ubuntu Linux has been that you can set up your virtual desktops without ever taking your hands off the keyboard. In the course of working on whatever you're working on, you can decide to launch an app with its hotkey, then decide only afterward that you'd rather put it in a new or other workspace, and send it there with another hotkey. No need to move a hand to mouse or touchpad. It's incredibly fast and efficient. I miss it greatly in Windows. In fact it's one of the reasons I now use Windows only for certain games or Adobe products.

Comment: I use Win key+tab in conjunction with CoolSwitch and AltTabSettings giving me a more versatile array as I keep over 40 windows open. Note, nasty little irritant that might not be obvious, it took me a while to connect the dots: at least on my Win 10, hitting Win+tab is turning off "automatically hide the taskbar". The taskbar goes to always-on-top every time I hit Win+tab.

Comment: Isn't this the same as https://superuser.com/a/950507/268750  ?

Comment: Thanks a lot!! It answers exactly the original question. Also wondering why so many people using some 3rd party stuff since there's an quick and easy way doing so... and if I need to get some 3rd party tools, install it, then it is not quick.

Answer (score 6):

**[zVirtualDesktop](https://github.com/mzomparelli/zVirtualDesktop)**

I'm using it for that purpose. It has keyboard shortcuts - which is great.
The developer is very responsive if you report an issue or ask a question or for a possible feature.

The best feature is `DesktopView` See below.

There are more options at GitHub, which I currently can't remember

**Here are some screenshots of zVirtualDesktop**

You can choose from these system tray icons
[image]

It has a really nice feature called `DesktopView` shown below. With this view you can drag and drop your windows to any desktop. It also works like Alt+Tab in that you can click a thumbnail to go to that window.
[image]

**Note:** *I answered this question about 1.5-2 years ago, with some hints to start developing something. But now, there are some solutions developed for this.
I added a new answer since there's no point in editing/improving my previous one, since they are totally different.*

Comment: There are many programs to do it but the OP is asking about the Virtual Desktop manager included in Windows.

Comment: I haven't used this, but [VirtuaWin](http://virtuawin.sourceforge.net/) is worth a try too, since it (1) [can auto catch programs into their own desktop](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/48103/6389), and (2) has addons to improve productivity.

Comment: I checked out zVirtualDesktop and it doesnt look trustworthy. Hosts on a Github but is closed source (apparently the source got removed), the older version that was apparently accidentally uploaded to Github (the exe is in the history) has a different usage license (private use is free forever) but autoupdates to the everyone-pays version... Also no mention of price on the site, only when you already launched it

Comment: VirtuaWin is fantastic. It does not manipulate windows 10 Virtual Desktop but it seems to hide/restore windows. I've been using it since XP, perfect for windows <10. In Win10 it has minor glitch but still very useful. Win10 native virtual desktop is clunky and incomplete in comparison.

Comment: why using some 3rd party stuff from a not trusted source when there's a built-in way doing so...

Answer (score 6):

Taking hints from the solutions of Greenonline and Sebastien:

1. Hit 'Win+Tab' for the Workspace Management View
2. Directional keys to navigate to the window of interest (if this was the last one in focus, it shouldn't be necessary).
3. Hit the 'Context' key for a dropdown menu (typically the key with the Windows logo between 'Ctrl' and 'Alt'), where you can select moving to other desktops.

So, not very straightforward, but definitely something you can easily automate your hands to do.

Comment: Completely agree. Not ideal, but I'd rather automate my hands to follow these simple steps than to install some third party, specially when they seem to be having modest maintenance.

Answer (score 4):

I use autohotkey with the keyboard shortcut CTRL+WIN+SHIFT+LEFT or RIGHT to push windows to the other virtual desktop.
I only use 2 virtual desktops, so this works for me regardless if i press left or right.

AHK Code:

```
#^+Left::
#^+Right::
Send #{tab}        ;WIN+TAB=Open the desktop view
Sleep 200
Send +{F10}M{Enter};SHIFT+F10=context menue. M=move. Enter for the first desktop in the list.
Sleep 100
Send #{tab}        ;WIN+TAB=Close the desktop view
return
```

Comment: Note that this only works (in a multi-monitor setup) for applications on the main monitor.  I needed to add a "Send {Left}{Right}" after the "Send #{tab}" to ensure that the application is actually selected before trying to move, or this did nothing.

Answer (score 4):

Given that Eun's MoveToDesktop is now unmaintained and no longer works, an alternative I've found for AutoHotKey is [VD.ahk](https://github.com/FuPeiJiang/VD.ahk).  It works on current versions of Windows 10 and 11.

Download the AHK files (as of this writing, the default branch shows files for AHK 1.x; support for AHK 2 can be found on an [alternate branch](https://github.com/FuPeiJiang/VD.ahk/tree/v2_port)) and add to your ahk script:

```
#Include VD.ahk
#!Left::VD.MoveWindowToRelativeDesktopNum("A", -1)
#!Right::VD.MoveWindowToRelativeDesktopNum("A", 1)
```

This binds to <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd>.

Comment: Worked well for me. I had to download `SetForeGroundWindow.exe` as well

Answer (score 2):

As of Windows 10 Version 1803, the simple way to move current/targeted window from 1 desktop to another is by following way:

1. Press **Win + Tab** to see the timeline.
2. Below Desktops section, you'll see the list of active running programs window under the current desktop. Click & hold the window and drag into specific desktop you want.
3. Voila!

Plus, its native and doesn't require any third party software.

Comment: And it means taking your hands off the keyboard – which is what the posts/comments above are trying to avoid.

Answer (score 2):

It ain't pretty but it doesn't use the mouse or any third-party software

<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>, <kbd>Arrow Down</kbd>, <kbd>Arrow Down</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>Arrow Down</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>Esc</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

For me `Shift + F10` doesn't work.

But this key is doing his job:

[image]

So I am able to move windows across desktop only with the keyboard navigating in the right click menu in the desktop preview view.

Answer (score 0):

Autohotkey solution. Bound to Win+Tilde key. This script automates all keystrokes that you would perform manually to send it to the next (if you're on the first) or previous desktop. Be careful though with such things - this can be dangerous if this input goes to wrong destination.

```
SendMode Input 
#`::
    send {blind}#{tab}
    sleep 1000
    send {appskey}
    sleep 300
    send {down}
    sleep 200
    send {down }
    sleep 200
    send {right}
    sleep 200
    send {left}
    sleep 200
    send {right}
    sleep 300
    send {enter}
    sleep 300
    send {esc}
    sleep 300
return
```

Answer (score -4):

simple press Winkey + Tab, now select the program (window) and drag it to the list of Desktops shown below (Desktop 1 or 2). Done. No other way..

Comment: "No other way" Clearly false as one of the other answer shows.

Comment: this is the best answer despite the negative votes

Comment: On one hand, since Microsoft keeps changing things to keep them interesting, none of the other answers here were working anymore at the time this was written, so what the author is trying to hint at with "No other way" is technically true. On the other hand, the author should learn to express themselves better than that.  (Also, there is no such thing as a "simple press". The author should learn how to use punctuation.)

Answer (score -8):

<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Arrow Left</kbd> / <kbd>Arrow  Right</kbd>

or

<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Arrow Left</kbd> / <kbd>Arrow  Right</kbd>

or

<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Arrow Up</kbd> / <kbd>Arrow  Down</kbd>

Comment: Those shortcuts do not move between virtual desktops.

Comment: It seems to move between multiple displays