# ctrl+win+shift+arrow not working

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, virtual-desktop

I just bought a new laptop. I've done all the windows updates and it's now at build 15063.

`ctrl+win+left/right` changes the virtual desktop as expected.
`ctrl+win+shift+left/right` is supposed to move the current window to the next desktop, but it behaves as if I've pressed Win+arrows (snapping the window).

The keyboard supports n key rollover, so all the keypresses are being registered and sent to windows properley.

Comment: 15063 is 1703 not 1709 by the way

Comment: yeah, windows update just found 1709 and is sloooowly downloading it now. Either way, 15063 should still have that shortcut, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no shortcut for this, see [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/950452/how-to-quickly-move-current-window-to-another-task-view-desktop-in-windows-10).

<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and then use the mouse to move the window to the wanted desktop is the best solution for now.

Other new shortcuts are in [this post](https://www.howtogeek.com/198122/32-new-keyboard-shortcuts-in-the-windows-10-technical-preview/).

Comment: That's from August 2015. Maybe out of date? There is most definitly a win+ctrl+shift+arrow. Works on my old laptop

Comment: Oh wait, nevermind, I'm stupid. I've been using Linux for too long. You are correct, that shortcut never existed in Windows