# Restoring Excel window with all tabs and commands

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel, virtuawin

In my Windows 10 laptop, I have Excel installed as a part of MS Office 365 Pro Plus. Also, for productivity convenience, I use VirtuaWin which provides me multiple desktops where I keep different types of applications running.

If excel is running in one such desktop, and I switch to a different one, Excel loses all its menus and commands and I do not even see the ribbon to restore these buttons. This occurs every time the Desktops are switched, both by keyboard shortcut (which is my usual practice) or mouse clicking.

I could not find any [keyboard shortcut](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/keyboard-shortcuts-in-excel-for-windows-1798d9d5-842a-42b8-9c99-9b7213f0040f) to restore. Clicking on the top left icon, or right click on title bar just displays standard options like minimize, maximize, close etc. Please let me know if anyone has encountered such issue or knows of a solution.

[image: Excel without menus]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also use VirtuaWin and have the same trouble. I found the way to restore Excel's menus. After losing menus, open printing window by Ctrl+p and just cancel to go back to sheet view, then the menu will be restored. 
I hope this trouble will be fixed soon.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 10, virtual desktops are a feature of Windows, so you don't need any
third-party product. Using this Windows feature, you will not have such problems.

Starting a new virtual desktop is done via the taskbar, using
*Task view > New desktop +*.

If you have turned off the Task view button, right-click the taskbar and choose
*Show Task View button*.

References:

- [Multiple desktops in Windows 10](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/4028538/windows-10-multiple-desktops)
- [How to use multiple desktops in Windows 10](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-use-multiple-desktops-windows-10)

---

For the question of easily moving windows between desktops, see the post
[How to quickly move current window to another task view / desktop in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/950452/how-to-quickly-move-current-window-to-another-task-view-desktop-in-windows-10).

One user lists his
[MoveToDesktop utility](https://github.com/Eun/MoveToDesktop)
that adds the shortcuts of
<kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd>,
as well as an addition to the right-click menu on the window's title.

Another listed tool is
[Windows 10 Virtual Desktop Enhancer](https://github.com/sdias/win-10-virtual-desktop-enhancer),
which is just a AutoHotkey script.

Comment: I know it does, but moving an application from one desktop to other cannot be done with simpler keyboard shortcuts and that's blocker in my view.

Comment: I expanded my answer.

Comment: Enhancer might be of help... will take a look.