# How to move window on invisible desktop to visible one?

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, multiple-desktop

I just read:

[How to quickly move current window to another Task View / desktop in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/950452/how-to-quickly-move-current-window-to-another-task-view-desktop-in-windows-10)

But most/all solutions assume you can see and interact with that window to be moved. What if you can't? What if the other desktop is on a monitor that's turned-off - and you want to bring the window over?

Note: I'm not referring to other virtual desktops, but rather - focused desktops on different monitors.

Comment: Can you see the window in Task View?

Comment: @harrymc: Right now I'm not at that computer, but - suppose that I can't. Or, ok, suppose that I can; that's one answer, at least.

Comment: The question you linked to is about virtual desktops, which implies that you want to know how to move a window from a non-focused virtual desktop to the focused desktop without switching to the non-focused virtual desktop. But the example you give of a second, turned-off monitor is an example of a second screen on a focused desktop. Which scenario is your question about?

Comment: @loopernow: See edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are able to set focus on the window, you can move it with the windows key + arrow to move between monitors.

You many need to press Win+Arrow repeatedly, as at first the window may switch to a position aligned to the side edge of the display, and then to the adjacent display on the next press.

Comment: There is a better shortcut that doesn't require repeated presses--see my answer.

Comment: It works! I didn't know about that keyboard shortcut. upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

A good question that has not yet been correctly resolved.
I am using Nirsoft's MultiMonitorTools here:
http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/multi_monitor_tool.html

You can enable preview of an invisible display - Monitor Preview. You can also move application windows between displays.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Set focus to the window with Alt-Tab, then use Win-Shift-arrow key (right or left arrow key, depending on "where" the turned-off monitor is in relation to the turned-on monitor) to send the window to the other monitor.

This Windows 10 keyboard shortcut is specifically for sending windows between monitors.

Comment: @einpoklum I don't believe so. Win+arrow key (the other answer) is a different keyboard shortcut from Win-Shift-arrow key (my answer). They have different behaviors.

Comment: Oh, I see. Sorry. I'll try that too.