# Application opens on wrong desktop, when using "Multiple desktops" in Windows

Tags: windows, multiple-desktop

I want to use Multiple Desktops to separate some tasks when I'm working. I guess like most users who use this feature. However when opening some applications that are already open on another desktop, **I get switched back to another desktop instead of opening another instance**. Like for example MS Teams or VS code. This is not the behaviour I would like.

Comment: AFAIK it depends on parameters for each application. Some applications are openned in single instance by default and this can be changed but some other can't be changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't find any way to keep it from opening in the wrong place, but you can move it quickly back to the right place with hotkeys. See [How to quickly move current window to another Task View / desktop in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/950452/how-to-quickly-move-current-window-to-another-task-view-desktop-in-windows-10)

Best answer is by @Eun:

> I think for a quicker switch this should be in the titlebar, so I created a tool for that:
>
> https://github.com/Eun/MoveToDesktop
>
> [image]
>
> You can also move windows by using <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd> or change the shortcut as needed.

The default is to just move the window. Change the [.ini file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Eun/MoveToDesktop/master/MoveToDesktop.ini) to also switch desktop after moving the window. You can also [adjust the hotkeys](https://github.com/Eun/MoveToDesktop/blob/master/help/keys.md) in this file. Also be sure to add the MoveToDesktop.exe to [your startup folder](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/add-an-app-to-run-automatically-at-startup-in-windows-10-150da165-dcd9-7230-517b-cf3c295d89dd).

Answer (score 1):

You can change behavior in Settings - System - Multitasking - Desktop - "On the taskbar show all the open windows" - "On the desktop I'm using". I've looking for changing behavior a viseversus and found this solution. It helped.