# Windows 10 keyboard shortcut for moving apps between desktops

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

(Related: [Are there any keyboard shortcuts for Windows 10 developer preview's virtual desktops ("Task View")?](https://superuser.com/questions/819433/))

I can switch between Task View desktops easily using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>.

Is there any keyboard shortcut to take the currently-focused *window* and move *it* to the next/previous Desktop?

It seems like the default workflow is intended to be:

1. <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>
2. Right-Click the window
3. Move To --> Desktop #

That's kind of annoying.

If there's no built-in keyboard shortcut, is there a program that can add one?

Comment: Scroll down to the green download button on the github page to download the exe file and run the file to enable the ability to press WIN+ALT+arrow left or right to switch the current window to the virtual desktop screen to the left or to the right. Press CTRL+WIN+arrow left or right to switch screens.